# how to place the react native transparent view above the native view?

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to place the react native view above the native view(ios opengl), like this:

```
  RCTRootView *rnView =[[RCTRootView alloc]initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleName:@"SimpleApp" initialProperties:nil launchOptions:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:rnView];
```

I try set style `backgroundColor:'transparent'`, But the background is white and I can not see native view behind.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the style with a style object on the javascript side, you should be able to make a `View` transparent by setting `opacity:0`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that set backgroundColor in ios can work.

`rnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.f alpha:0.f];`